# Is there a way of sending commands to a terminal application in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, console

I am running linux as you might have already figured out.
So I wrote a gameserver panel in PHP and Python that can install, start and stop any game I write a script for. After some testing with mumble, I am now adding games to the list and my first game to be supported will be quakelive. **What I want to achieve is that I can send commands to any application that is running in a terminal and also read the output to the console window.**. My next steps will be Minecraft and some other games. I know that these 2 games have a query port, but a) I don't know how to send a query from php to this and b) I want to potentially support every game there is.

**Just for the record, I can extract a process id from a running process already, if that helps.**

So I ran ps aux | grep qzero and it says that the server is opened on pts/2. So the command I am testing with is pause, when I type it in manually, it echos back some stuff.

Online I found the command

```
echo pause > /dev/pts/2
```

But all it really does is echoing pause into the console window.

**I have been searching online but I think I don't really know what to look for. Maybe it has something to do with this whole stdin and stdout stuff.**

I know this is possible in other languages since I've fiddled around in PufferPanel and they have this feature, too. But it has some flaws so I decided to code my own panel.

Answer (score 0):

So actually it was not that hard. I did not find a solution to send it directly to a terminal, but with the help of tmux, it could be done.

You basically start a session and then

```
tmux send-keys -t sessionname -l command

tmux send-keys -t sessionname Enter
```

And this is no problem integrating into an application in Python.

see further https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi

Can also be done in screen apparently.